The LSTM training model predicts results that consistently form a horizontal line without any amplitude
The code of LSTM models:
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,num_layers,output_size,batch_size,seq_length) -> None:
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.input_size=input_size
        self.hidden_size=hidden_size
        self.num_layers=num_layers
        self.output_size=output_size
        self.batch_size=batch_size
        self.seq_length=seq_length
        self.num_directions=1 
        self.liner1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.liner2 = nn.Linear(num_layers*hidden_size, output_size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2)
 
        self.lstm=nn.LSTM(input_size=hidden_size,hidden_size=hidden_size,num_layers=num_layers,batch_first=True,dropout=0.2) # LSTM
 
    def forward(self,x):
        batchsize = x.shape[0]
        x = self.liner1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
 
        h_0 = torch.randn(self.num_directions * self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to('cuda')
        c_0 = torch.randn(self.num_directions * self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to('cuda')
 
        output, (h_n, c_n) = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0)) 
 
        output = h_n.permute(1,0,2).reshape(batchsize, -1) # 64,10,32  -> 64,32*2
        pred = self.dropout(output)
        pred = self.liner2(pred)     
        pred = pred[:, -1]     # (batch_size,)
        return pred         

the code of Config:
    # 参数设置
    seq_length = 10  # 时间步长
    input_size = 3  # 原本为3，现在为5， 删去postcode与time
    num_layers = 2 # 4
    hidden_size = 128 # 512??
    batch_size = 64
    n_iters = 10000 # 50000 5000
    lr = 0.0001
    output_size = 1
    split_ratio = 0.9
    path = 'data/raw_sales.csv'
    moudle = Net(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size, batch_size, seq_length)
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(moudle.parameters(), lr=lr)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()

and the result picture:
enter image description here
the total data is about 10thousand(10000)
so here is the question, i have changed the hidden_size and seq_size(windows_size),but the picture barely changed.the line is always horizontal.
1.change the hidden_size from 3 to 128、256、512
2.change the windows_size from 3 to 7、10、30
3.change the iters to a large number
expecting:
the line could have amplitude,for example,it could be more slash.
4.20 23:30
the loss plot:
enter image description here
the datasets link:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/htagholdings/property-sales/data
i use the raw_data instead of processed data.
i have tried the proceesed data which is shorter and flatter than the raw data,the result seems to be cool,i guess its beacuse the raw_data always change which is not suitable for predict
the new result plot is here:
enter image description here
4/22 0:30
i have resample the data by monthly or quarterly,and the result seems so good:
enter image description here

I haven't found anything wrong with the code you've shown, so I think the problem is elsewhere. Might help if you could provide some sample data.

i have tried the proceesed data which is shorter and flatter than the raw data,the result seems to be cool,i guess its beacuse the raw_data always change which is not suitable for predict?

The raw data is irregular, but the processed data is quarterly. I think the irregular data would be a problem for the LSTM, so you may want to resample it to make it regular (e.g. monthly). Which features are you using?

yeah,i have resample it by monthly or quarterly,and the result seems so good,thanks a lot!!

No problem, glad it's better.
